Совершенно неважен - слитно или раздельно
"совершенно неважен" в данном контексте слитно или раздельно?
А мужчинам, как выяснилось, совершенно неважен характер, если талия недостаточно тонка или нос неизящен.

Слитно: совершенно неважен, усиление утверждения: краткое прилагательное + наречие степени, Розенталь, пункт 6 http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77

«Неважно» пишется слитно в значении «плохо» («он что-то неважно выглядит»). Это один случай. В остальных — он может писаться и слитно, и раздельно. И эту тонкую грань нужно уловить. Если коротко, то когда мы утверждаем важность — слитно. Если отрицаем важность — раздельно. Ну вы поняли, что всё сложно. Чаще всего отдаётся предпочтение слитному написанию, особенно если мысленно можно подобрать утвердительный синоним. А если подразумевается противопоставление или есть пояснительные слова с дополнительным отрицанием («далеко не важно», «ничуть не важно», «отнюдь не важно»), тогда раздельно. То же самое относится к наречиям «невозможно» и «неизвестно».

Независимо от частей речи есть сигнальные слова, которые намекают нам, что дальше никаких пробелов — пишем слитно. Это слова, обозначающие так называемую степень качества («очень», «крайне», «весьма», «совершенно», «вполне», «слишком», «абсолютно»). Они сигнализируют о том, что следующие слова с частицей «не» пишутся слитно. «Очень непродуманное решение задания», «совершенно неподходящий пример» и так далее.
источник

А мужчинам, как выяснилось, совершенно неважен характер, если талия недостаточно тонка или нос неизящен.
